# Sorting multiple array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Can someone help me i need to sort this array:

```
$report_fields['client_id'] = $row['client_id'];
$report_fields['name'] = $row['name'];
$report_fields['is_authorized'] = $row['is_authorized'];
$report_fields['date_created'] = $row['date_created'];
$report_fields['service_id'] = $row['service_id'];
$report_fields['type_id'] = $row['type_id'];
$report_fields['report_name'] = $report_types[$row['type_id']]['type'];


$report_groups[$row['ref_no']][$row['id']] = $report_fields;
```

I have tried usort like so:

```
usort($report_groups[$row['ref_no']],'cmp');

function cmp($a,$b) { 
   $a_stm = strtotime($a["date_created"]);
   $b_stm = strtotime($b["date_created"]);

   if ($a_stm == $b_stm) {
    return 0;
    }

   return ($a_stm < $b_stm) ? -1 : 1;

}
```

But the result returned is incorrect.

Comment: Is there any error message with E_ALL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_multisort is what you want to use.

Here's an example

```
<?php

$sort = array(
    array(),
    array()
);

foreach ($results as $k=>$result) {
    $sort[0][$k] = $result['sort_field_one'];
    $sort[1][$k] = $result['sort_field_two'];   
}


# sort using $sort[0] DESC and $sort[1] ASC
array_multisort($sort[0], SORT_DESC, $sort[1], SORT_DESC, $results);
```